# Analytic Number Theory - Prerequisites

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

I'm interested in studying Analytic Number Theory using Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory.

Having looked briefly at Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory and having read the reviews, I can see that complex analysis is assumed in this book.

In my degree I studied some complex analysis (up to and including the residue theorem). However this was things like using Laurent Series, contour integration methods and stuff - I'm not sure if that would count as complex 'analysis' (as this was not a hugely rigorous course (in the sense that a Real Analysis course would cover deriving the derivative and stuff by use of limits, convergence etc)).

Also I did not study any real analysis. I also studied a lot of pure maths (group theory, ring and field theory, number theory).

Would it be sufficient (or necessary) to go over:

Basic real analysis (up to convergence of functions).
based on the book:
http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781493927111
up to the chapter 'Functional Limits and Continuity'
and

Complex Variable up to and including the residue theorem (based on this book:
https://www.pearsonhighered.com/program/Osborne-Complex-Variables-and-their-Applications/PGM271956.html
Chapters 1-5 (in particular, is this rigorous enough for a prerequisite to Analytic Number Theory? This was the book used when I was an undergraduate (in actual fact taught by the author)

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: I've known many students who have learned out of that book in class with nothing more than sophomore level math maturity (calculus, differential equations, maybe intro to abstract algebra) and have done fine.  My disclaimer would be - read slow, work through the problems, and reread many times.  Then youll be fine.

Comment: When you say 'calculus' are you including the rigour of real analysis in this or do you mean calculus as in being able to do integration, differentiation etc? (That is, the techniques without proofs)

Comment: I mean like sophomore level math... if your idea of sophomore level math is proving the Riesz Kakutani theorem, then you are definitely ready.  But to me it seems like just knowing mathematical notation and having sufficient patience will do you fine.  Of course, knowing more math wont hurt... neither will trying to read a book that you may (or may not) be prepared for, so go for it.

Comment: I believe that a good strategy is add as companion of **Apostol**'s book the following **Murty**, *Problems in Analytic Number Theory*, **Springer** GTM-RIM (2008). Some contents from (parts of) correspond to chapters of this book were in videos from the official channel **mathsciencechannel** (IMSc) in **Youtube**: *matsciencechannel, Ram Murty Lectures, Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*, (the teacher in the video is the author of the book). Then you can see such techniques: summation, tauberian theorems, contour integration, equidistribution... There are about 6 or 7 videos, good luck.

Comment: Davenport's book is also a good next step if you want to study this subject at a graduate level.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a few years, but I once taught a course out of that book.  As far as I can recall, the complex analysis you need is contour integration.  I don't recall any "functional limits".  There is a good bit of analyzing average values of arithmetic functions, so things like $F(n) =(1/n) \sum_{k=1}^n \sigma(k).$  But it's not much more complicated than the Series chapter in a calculus book.  I think you're good to go.

Comment: How much real analysis does one need for intro level number theory ?

Comment: In terms of specific knowledge, not much other than "mathematical maturity" ie being able to use logic notation, reading and writing proofs etc